# On the computation of the Hessian matrix.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, hessian-matrix

I'm trying to compute the Hessian matrix of a data fit of an ODE model to some data. Below is a cut out of the instructions I'm following (which can also be found at `Gutenkunst, R.N., Waterfall, J.J., Casey, F.P., Brown, K.S., Myers, C.R. and Sethna, J.P. (2007) 'Universally Sloppy Parameter Sensitivities in Systems Biology Models', PLoS Comput Biol, 3(10), p. e189`).

The function I'm trying to compute the hessian matrix for is:

[image]

with:

$ ϴ = $to a parameter vector for ODE model

$ N_c=$Number of experimental conditions

$ N_s=$Number of model variables/species

$ T_c=$measurement time

$ Y_sc(ϴ,t)= $timecourse for species $s$ in condition $c$ given parameters ϴ

$ sigma^2= $ Normalization - maximum value of species $s$ over all $c$

$  $
$  $

And in the paper they define the Hessian Matrix as:

[image]

My question is: how do I use this information to compute the hessian matrix for a simple set of ODEs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your description, the Hessian will have entries $(j,k)$ equal to
$$
\frac1{2N_cN_s}\sum_{s,c}\frac1{T_c}\int_0^{T_c}\frac{y_{s,c}(\theta,t)-y_{s,c}(\theta^*,t)}{\sigma_s^2}\cdot\frac{\partial^2y_{s,c}(\theta,t)}{\partial(\log\theta_j)\partial(\log\theta_k)}\,dt.
$$